# Why %USERDOMAIN% is not "NT AUTHORITY" for SYSTEM user?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, windows-services

Running the following command

```
set USERDOMAIN
set USERNAME
```

in a Windows service will return

```
USERDOMAIN=MY_CORPORATE_DOMAIN
USERNAME=SYSTEM
```

But my service was running in "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM".

My Questions are:

1. Why is `USERDOMAIN` is "MY_CORPORATE_DOMAIN" not "NT AUTHORITY"?
2. If I want to run `taskkill` as shown below to kill my process under the current user.

   - It won't run correctly in SYSTEM user, because userdomain
     return MY_CORPORATE_DOMAIN, which should return NT AUTHORITY.

How
    can I rewrite the command?

```
 taskkill /F /FI "USERNAME eq %userdomain%\%username%" /IM my_process.exe
```

Comment: Use `SC stop [service_name]` to stop the service instead of killing it.

Answer (score 0):

On a domain, the `SYSTEM` user uses the credentials of the Active Directory machine account under some circumstances, this being one of them. Computers have accounts too; their SAM names are just the computer name with an extra `$` at the end. Therefore, a computer named `CATACLYSM` in the `INFERNO` domain would get `INFERNO\CATACLYSM$` in response to `echo %userdomain%\%username%`.

If you want to get `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` for programs running as `SYSTEM`, use the `whoami` utility. Sadly, there's not a nice way in Windows batch to put the output of a command in a variable. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6359924/2825369) would suggest you do something like this:

```
whoami > tmp-whoami
set /p currentuser= < tmp-whoami
del tmp-whoami
```

You would then be able to use `%currentuser%` in place of `%userdomain%\%username%`.